# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. No clue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get the above error when I try to run this query

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT @ColumnNames=Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename([COL1])
               FROM table1
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM

( SELECT 
   [COL1]
  ,[COL2]
FROM 
  FROM table1 ) AS BaseData

PIVOT(
 COUNT([COL2])
 FOR [COL1]
 IN('+@ColumnNames +
 ')
) As PivotTable'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always use `Print` statement to debug dynamic query.

Comment: Also its a good idea to check the error message for a clue (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `from`s in the query.

```
FROM FROM table1 --change this
```